# .NET Google Calendar API v3 : mutilple account authentification

Tags: calendar, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to write a program that will synchronize events between a CRM and Google Calendar of several Google accounts.

It's a Windows Console application.

For each Google account, in the API Console I enabled the Calendar API, created an application named "UpdateSync" (type : native) then downloaded the JSON file.

I renamed those files using the account mail address (ie email1@gmail.com.json)

Next, I wrote the code bellow :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads updated event from Google Calender after last synchonization date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="user">The user we want to get appointments</param>
    public List<Appointment> LoadAppointments(User user)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("LoadAppointments({0})", user.Email);
        List<Appointment> Appointments = new List<Appointment>();

        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(string.Format("credentials\\{0}.json", user.Email), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            try
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets, new[] { CalendarService.Scope.Calendar }, "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("UpdayeSync.Credentials")).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
        initializer.ApplicationName = "UpdateSync";
        service = new CalendarService(initializer);

        EventsResource.ListRequest req = service.Events.List("primary");
        req.TimeMin = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-2).ToString("o");
        req.ShowDeleted = true;
        req.UpdatedMin = XmlConvert.ToString(LastSync, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
        req.SingleEvents = true;

        Events events;
        try
        {
            events = req.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            return null;
        }

        // [...]
    }
```

This code is called for each JSON file.

At the first call, the account to synchronize was "email1@gmail.com".
Google Chrome automatically oppened, and auto-logged with my own account (email2@gmail.com) and asked me to allow my program to access Calendar API.

I accepted.

This popup never shown again.

Any change done for any account was done on my own calendar, not the one the JSON files refer to.

What's wrong ? How to access several Google accounts with a unique program ?

This program will run on a server as a scheduled task, and I must not open any window, as noone will look at the server's screen. I can't ask the user to authentificate himself, as there is not user.

But I can do anything on the Google account of any of the users (enabling API, creating keys, granting application, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

You should create a new CalendarService (lightweight component) per user. CalendarService and all other Google services are implemented as immutables (for simplicity and to support thread-safe operations).

Create a new service for each user and use a different userId ("user1", "user2", etc.) as a parameter to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync.

UPDATE:

You should also create your own class of flow:

> ```
> class ForceUIGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow : AuthorizationCodeFlow
> {
>     public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
>     {
>         return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
>         {
>             ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
>             Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
>             RedirectUri = redirectUri,
>             ApprovalPrompt = "force",
>         };
>     }
> }
> ```

and then,

replace the your call to  GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker with the following code:

> ```
> var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
> {
>        ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
>        Scopes = [SCOPED_HERE];
>        initializer.DataStore = new FileDataStore("Credentials");
> };
> var flow = new ForceUIGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer);
> ```

```
// Create authorization code installed app instance and authorize the user.
crdentials = await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, 
      new LocalServerCodeReceiver()).AuthorizeAsync
      ("USER_ID_HERE", taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Hello. As far as I know, that's what I did : I have a class "GoogleExtractor" with a Load method (source like the one above). Next, I have another class that instanciate GoogleExtractor objects in a loop, one per user. I tried to remplace "user" constant in the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() call by the user login (GMail address) but it doesn't change anything : I connect always on the Google account my Google Chrome is associated with, even if this account should not be called by my program.

Comment: @StringBuilder,It is better to use Google Client sdk where no any api key generation required.

Comment: Doesn't work any different to using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker for me. Problem is once I'm logged into Google in the browser, even specifying a different user ID / email, the browser just presents the consent screen for my own account. No prompt for the account specified.

For calendars the only solution seems to be to use service accounts and share the calendar with the service account (which to be fair is what Google recommend)

Comment: Update - to expand on the last comment. If I set LoginHint in GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl to the email then it helps, but it doesn't force it to that email. The user can then type in whatever they like. If they have an existing account logged in they can click that. Problem with this in my case is I can see it will cause confusion with some users. Worse than that though is if the user email is invalid / not registered on Google, it will just use the current authenticated user.